# Python: Convert bytes to json

Tags: python

im having this byte class

```
b'ToCountry=US&ToState=WA&SmsMessageSid=SM2c04173b9a5f684be8019e177978c791&NumMedia=0&ToCity=&FromZip=&SmsSid=SM2c04173b9a5f684be8019e177978c791&FromState=&SmsStatus=received&FromCity=&Body=Bbjhggggggg&FromCountry=EE&To=%2B15095121752&ToZip=&NumSegments=1&ReferralNumMedia=0&MessageSid=SM2c04173b9a5f684be8019e177978c791&AccountSid=ACee01b40141d9e1237769375c269f4a76&From=%2B37253055607&ApiVersion=2010-04-01'
```

how can i convert to json

Answer (score 3):

One line solution

```
a = b'ToCountry=US&ToState=WA&SmsMessageSid=SM2c04173b9a5f684be8019e177978c791&NumMedia=0&ToCity=&FromZip=&SmsSid=SM2c04173b9a5f684be8019e177978c791&FromState=&SmsStatus=received&FromCity=&Body=Bbjhggggggg&FromCountry=EE&To=%2B15095121752&ToZip=&NumSegments=1&ReferralNumMedia=0&MessageSid=SM2c04173b9a5f684be8019e177978c791&AccountSid=ACee01b40141d9e1237769375c269f4a76&From=%2B37253055607&ApiVersion=2010-04-01'

dict = {e.split("=")[0]:e.split("=")[1] for e in a.decode().split("&")}

{'ToCountry': 'US', 'ToState': 'WA', 'SmsMessageSid': 'SM2c04173b9a5f684be8019e177978c791', 'NumMedia': '0', 'ToCity': '', 'FromZip': '', 'SmsSid': 'SM2c04173b9a5f684be8019e177978c791', 'FromState': '', 'SmsStatus': 'received', 'FromCity': '', 'Body': 'Bbjhggggggg', 'FromCountry': 'EE', 'To': '%2B15095121752', 'ToZip': '', 'NumSegments': '1', 'ReferralNumMedia': '0', 'MessageSid': 'SM2c04173b9a5f684be8019e177978c791', 'AccountSid': 'ACee01b40141d9e1237769375c269f4a76', 'From': '%2B37253055607', 'ApiVersion': '2010-04-01'}
```

Comment: `%2B15095121752` should likely become `+15095121752`, that's why there's [`urllib.parse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs).

Comment: @bereal thank you, yes im getting what i want,  number is still %2B15095121752 still like this, how to use parse?

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard module [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html), which will also take care about `%`-encoded symbols:

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl

url = 'ToCountry=US&ToState=WA&To=%2B15095121752' # ...etc
result = dict(parse_qsl(url))
```

Comment: perfect! i'm getting real values but rest of the code where I used {e.split("=")[0]:e.split("=")[1] for e in a.decode().split("&")} is broken

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following Python libraries:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

For example:

```
import json
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
raw_data = b'ToCountry=US&ToState=WA&SmsMessageSid=SM2c04173b9a5f684be8019e177978c791&NumMedia=0&ToCity=&FromZip=&SmsSid=SM2c04173b9a5f684be8019e177978c791&FromState=&SmsStatus=received&FromCity=&Body=Bbjhggggggg&FromCountry=EE&To=%2B15095121752&ToZip=&NumSegments=1&ReferralNumMedia=0&MessageSid=SM2c04173b9a5f684be8019e177978c791&AccountSid=ACee01b40141d9e1237769375c269f4a76&From=%2B37253055607&ApiVersion=2010-04-01'

param_data = parse_qs(raw_data.decode())
json_data = json.dumps(param_data, indent=4)
print(json_data)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
{
    "ToCountry": [
        "US"
    ],
    "ToState": [
        "WA"
    ],
    "SmsMessageSid": [
        "SM2c04173b9a5f684be8019e177978c791"
    ],
    "NumMedia": [
        "0"
    ],
    "SmsSid": [
        "SM2c04173b9a5f684be8019e177978c791"
    ],
    "SmsStatus": [
        "received"
    ],
    "Body": [
        "Bbjhggggggg"
    ],
    "FromCountry": [
        "EE"
    ],
    "To": [
        "+15095121752"
    ],
    "NumSegments": [
        "1"
    ],
    "ReferralNumMedia": [
        "0"
    ],
    "MessageSid": [
        "SM2c04173b9a5f684be8019e177978c791"
    ],
    "AccountSid": [
        "ACee01b40141d9e1237769375c269f4a76"
    ],
    "From": [
        "+37253055607"
    ],
    "ApiVersion": [
        "2010-04-01"
    ]
}
```